# -regtest generate 101 not working

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli, regtest

when I type

```
bitcoin-cli -regtest generate 101
```

in the powershell it gives me this error:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon> ./bitcoin-cli -regtest generate 101
error code: -32601
error message:
```

I am running bitcoind in regtest too ,this is the last message that I got fom bitcoind:

```
Adding fixed seed nodes as DNS doesn't seem to be available.
```

please help

Answer (score 1):

the answer is :

bitcoin-cli -regtest generatetoaddress < nblocks > < address >